# Linking two python dictionaries

Tags: python, dictionary

I'm struggling on the code to link two python dictionaries together:

```
d1 = {'a':'Apple','b':'Banana'}
d2 = {'Apple':'Pomme','Banana':'Banane'}
```

I want to create a new dictionary d3 where 'a' is a key for the value 'Pomme' and 'b' is the key for value 'Banane'.

```
d3 = {'a':'Pomme','b':'Banane'}
```

Any guidance would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 9):

Using a dictionary comprehension:

```
d3 = {k: d2[v] for k, v in d1.items()}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want a *dynamic* linking, means if you want the new mapping to reflect changes made to original dicts, you can derive a class from `collections.abc.Mapping`:

```
class DLinker(collections.abc.Mapping):
    def __init__(self, d1, d2):
        self.d1 = d1
        self.d2 = d2
    def __len__(self):
        return len(self.d1)
    def __getitem__(self, item):
        return d2[d1[item]]
    def __iter__(self):
        return iter(d1)
```

You can then use:

```
>>> d3 = DLinker(d1, d2)
>>> for i in d3:
    print(i, d3[i])


a Pomme
b Banane
>>> d1['c'] = 'Pear'
>>> d2['Pear'] = 'Poire'
>>> d3['c']
'Poire'
```

Comment: For OP's benefit, the result of this method `d3` isn't a `dict` but a subclass of `collections.abc.Mapping`. Having said this, you'll find most of the benefits of a `dict`. It will be efficient for very large dictionaries where you do not want to repeat data. But less efficient for small dictionaries where 2 lookups are required.